# INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY when using a custom library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, android-manifest

I'm using [CloudApp Java Wrapper](https://github.com/simong/CloudAppJava), this is my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.github.cloudapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.api" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.api.model" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.impl" />
    <uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.impl.model" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I keep getting `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` check LogCat, but on LogCat there is nothing there, I'm sure I correctly declared the library in the manifest. What am I doing wrong? Are the packages names wrong? I'm using the jar from [here](https://github.com/simong/CloudAppJava/downloads).

Here is also the screenshot of the library:

[image]

Comment: have you included all the libraries that are mentioned in uses-library tag?

Comment: @nandeesh I think so, I've added a screenshot to my post of the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove these lines from `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.api" />
<uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.api.model" />
<uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.impl" />
<uses-library android:name="com.cloudapp.impl.model" />
```

You only need to use these tags when you happens to use `shared-libraries`, which are `*.so` files, which are usually at `/libs` directories. These `shared-libraries` are loaded at run-time; however, your `references-libraries` are built with projects at compile-time.